# Error while using npm install in spring boot application created using JHipster

Tags: angular, spring-boot, web-applications, jhipster, npm-install

I have generated a new Spring Boot+Angular JHipster application and I'm getting an error on "npm install"

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...12-75IgJJaF8pSxZxcG8v'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

below text is from the log file

```
3614 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...12-75IgJJaF8pSxZxcG8v'
3614 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
3614 verbose stack     at parseJson (D:\Installed\WebDevelopment\npm-global\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
3614 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (D:\Installed\WebDevelopment\npm-global\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)
3614 verbose stack     at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)
3615 verbose cwd D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack
3616 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
3617 verbose argv "D:\\Installed\\WebDevelopment\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Installed\\WebDevelopment\\npm-global\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
3618 verbose node v11.2.0
3619 verbose npm  v6.14.4
3620 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...12-75IgJJaF8pSxZxcG8v'
```

any ideas on what could be causing it and how to resolve

Comment: Try to install an LTS version of node and then run `npm cache clean`, retry generating your project.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thanks. It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to  @GaëlMarziou's comment this error didn't appear after:

Installing **LTS Version of Node** and running `npm cache clean --force`